# Got an Error while building android project

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-build

I'm a beginner in android's development,I installed all the Build tools and the extras,API 8,11,14,17,19,20.
I create a new project which I compile with the API 17 (the target SDK is API 17).
But when i run the project many errors appear:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name                
'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75                  
 Android      AAPT Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library   
'C:\Users\SLIM\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar' NewProject      Build path  Build   `Path Problem`

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    NewProject      Unknown Java   
Problem
```

I have read the most answers of that problem published on the site but it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: `and the extras,API 8,11,14,17,19,20` - You need the API Level **21** SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the API Level 21 in addition to the ones you have.
The `'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21` seems to be requesting the API Level 21, so that might just work.

Comment: Exactly as I said in my `comment`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see that!

Comment: the problem that I choose the API level 17 to compile the project but on the activity_main.xml i find API level 21 chosen when i switch it to API level 17 it doesn't work.